# .net core web api (cross domain), posting image base64String via ajax not working

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send a couple of parameters (including base64String) from my site domain (https://localhost/site1) to a web api hosted on domain (https://localhost/siteAPI)

Here is my ajax all

```
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('base64image', base64ImageContent);
            
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost/SiteAPI/api/PdfCreator',
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            });
```

My API Controller :

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
    public class PdfCreatorController : ControllerBase

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateImage([FromBody]string base64image)
        {
            return Ok();
            
        }
```

This is how the image is extracted from the canvas chart (using chartjs) :

```
var base64ImageContent = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
```

The data in the post action is always null, and I am also getting this type of error :

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|66d9ee0a-401aa3e22a2bb6e1."}

EDIT:
here is the form HTML (do I need to submit this form to make the post work ?)

```
<form asp-controller="Assessments" asp-action="List" method="post">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible " id="alert" role="alert">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline mb-3">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="chkGetAll" asp-for="IncludeInactive">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkGetAll">Include Inactive Assessments?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow: auto; height: 450px;">
                <div id="divHidden" style="width:700px;height:450px;">
                    <canvas id="canvas" height="10" width="10"></canvas>
                    <img id="canvasimage" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have very few hair left on my head, please help !

Comment: any update? Does my reply answer your questions?

Answer (score 0):

UrL: https://localhost/SiteAPI/api/**PdfCreator**

Controller Action: **CreateImage**

You seems to be redirecting to the wrong **Action**

Comment: the action is fine since in the api there is only 1 post method, the breakpoint works but the action method parameter is null. Also have updated my question with the HTML part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to remove the `[FromBody]` and use `[FromForm]`. Like below:

```
    public IActionResult CreateImage([FromForm]string base64image)
```

According to your codes, I found you passed a form data from ajax to the web api.  But you has added a frombody in your web api as the model binding attribute.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody):

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter.

The frombody doesn't support `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, it will not model bind the data to the `base64image`. This is the reason why the string value is always null.

Here is a test demo.

I use below ajax to send the request and get the data in the action:

```
<script>
    function getUploadedFile(Sle) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:5001/api/Values/CreateImage",
            data: { "base64image": Sle.value} ,
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#uploadedFile").val(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateImage([FromForm] string base64image)
    {
        return Ok();

    }
```

Result:

[image]